# What are the DC motor wires in the picture for?

Tags: motor, dc

[image]

I'm given a DC motor without any specs. But it is not pwm thats I'm sure. The point is there are 3 wires brown, red-black. red-white. I cant find out how to power the motor and which wire is gnd or plus.

Comment: Any part number or manufacturer visible? Can you nondestructively remove the metal casing and look at the windings?

Comment: My guess is either DC over the two red wires + tachometer on brown, or some kind of 3-phase brushless: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27329/how-to-tell-if-brushless-dc-motor-is-wired-delta-or-y?rq=1

Comment: I found some info it it this one but still cannot know how to power this: http://songtian.gmc.globalmarket.com/products/details/radiator-cooling-fan-motors-assemblies-1j0-959-455f-for-vw-196762.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there is an engine coolant fan from some sort of VW vehicle.

According to page 97-940 of the VW Jetta/Golf/GTI 1999-2005 service manual published by Bentley Publishers, brown-black and red-black go across the motor, and red-black and red-white go across some sort of resistive sense device, possibly some sort of thermal device. I can't supply an image of the service manual, but the fan is either device V7 or V35 on the aforementioned page.

The fan itself is meant to be connected to the coolant fan controller (J293), but unfortunately I have no further information on said device.